# Session Variable No Longer Working

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I feel I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at a problem I have which I can't see a solution to.

The form below is used to list `Location records` held in a MySQL database.

```
    <form name="locationsconsole" id="locationsconsole" method="post" action="locationsaction.php">

                                    <?php

                                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `userid` = '$idnum' ORDER BY locationname";
                                        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('error');
                                        $num = mysql_numrows($result);
                                        mysql_close($connect);                  
                                        $i=0;
                                        while ($i < $num) {
                                        $lid=mysql_result($result,$i,"locationid");
                                        $lname=mysql_result($result,$i,"locationname");
                                        $laddress=mysql_result($result,$i,"returnedaddress");

                             <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" id="lid" name="lid" value="<?=$lid?>"/></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $lname;?></div></td>
                                <td><div align="left"><?php echo $laddress;?></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $findscount?></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Details"/></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="Add Finds"/></div></td>
                                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="Add Images"/></div></td>
                                <td><div align="left"><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Location Finds"/></div></td>
                            </tr>

    </form>
```

Using the code below, the four buttons at the end of my form take the user to four separate screens, all linked back to the `Location record` via the `$lid variable`.

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['lid'] = $_POST['lid'];
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $urls = array(
        'View Details' => 'viewlocation.php',
        'Add Finds' => 'addfinds.php',
        'Add Images' => 'addimages.php',
        'View Location Finds' => 'locationfinds.php'
    );
    $url = $urls[$_POST['type']];
    header("Location: " . $url);
}
?>
```

All of the four receiving forms therefore have this `$lid = $_SESSION['lid'];` at the top of each page to capture this variable.

This architecture worked perfectly up to a few days ago, and it's now all gone awry and I'm not sure why. I know that this field `<input type="text" id="lid" name="lid" value="<?=$lid?>"/>` in my form is holding the correct value.

However, irrespective of how many `Locations records` there are, if I click on any button I'm taken to the correct receiving screens, but it's always for the last 'Location` record in the list.

I just can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong here, or understand why it's now started to cause me problems. I've checked the JavaScript console in Chrome, and that's not showing me any errors either.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please an let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: `$num = mysql_numrows($result);`???  The function is called `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: Also, you are closing the connection via `mysql_close()` before retrieving any rows.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thank you for helping me with this. I've made the alterations to my code to see what would happen, and unfortunately the problem s are still occurring. Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your "lid" inputs are in the same form. When you submit your form, all values are sent and only the last one get into your $_POST array. Move form tags to the inside of your loop (that means generate many forms) ant it should work fine.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `userid` = '$idnum' ORDER BY locationname";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('error');
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close($connect);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $lid=mysql_result($result,$i,"locationid");
    $lname=mysql_result($result,$i,"locationname");
    $laddress=mysql_result($result,$i,"returnedaddress");

    ?><form name="locationsconsole" id="locationsconsole" method="post" action="locationsaction.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="lid" name="lid" value="<?=$lid?>"/></td>
                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $lname;?></div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><?php echo $laddress;?></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><?php echo $findscount?></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Details"/></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="Add Finds"/></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><input name="type" type="submit" value="Add Images"/></div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><input name="type" type="submit" value="View Location Finds"/></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form><?php
}
```

Comment: Hi @Donatas Olsevičius, I'm very sorry to be a little slow, here but I'm relatively new to this. Could you perhaps elaborate a little more ans show me where I need to move the form tag? Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Donatas Olsevičius, thank you very much for this. I've amended my code, to your suggestion and unfortunately instead of locations being listed, there is an onscreen error which just says `error`. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: That means there is a problem with your sql query or connection. You must have replaced more than you had to :) Undo until you find your original code and only replace the necessary part.

Comment: Hi @Donatas Olsevičius, thank you very much this. I've been reading quite a few posts on other sites, and I'm wondering whether it's something my server provider has done, it seems to be a common problem. I've tried forms which I know haven't been changed for weeks and I still have the same problem. So it may suggest the problem is elsewhere. Once again thank you for your time and trouble. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

'mysql_numrows'

Should be:

'mysql_num_rows'

Comment: Hi @maxhud. Thank you for helping me with this. I've made the change, but , unfortunately I still have the same problems. Kind regards and thanks.